# R - Convert a Character Vector into a Data Frame

Tags: r

This seems like it should be a fairly simple problem, but I can't seem to find a straightforward solution.

I have a character list that looks like this:

```
my_info <- c("Fruits",
             "North America",
             "Apples",
             "Michigan",
             "Europe",
             "Pomegranates",
             "Greece",
             "Oranges",
             "Italy",
             "Vegetables",
             "North America",
             "Potatoes",
             "Idaho",
             "Avocados",
             "California",
             "Europe",
             "Artichokes",
             "Italy",
             "Meats",
             "North America",
             "Beef",
             "Illinois")
```

I want to parse this character vector into a data frame that looks like this:

[screenshot of R console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZOy1.png)

The food types and the region lists will always remain the same, but the foods and their locations are subject to change.

```
food_type <- c("Fruits","Vegetables","Meats")
region <- c("North America","Europe")
```

I was thinking I needed to use something like str_split, but use the food_types and regions as some sort of a delimiter? But I am not sure how to proceed. The character vector does have an order to it.

Thank you.

Comment: So you do have reference lists like `food_type` and `region` that you can use to split the original data into multiple columns? Is there a meaning to the rows you wish to have in the final result, or do you just want to have columns that represent the different categories? Thanks :)

Comment: How exactly did you get the data in that form in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have reference lists. The food_type and region are limited to those specified, but the food and location variables can change (as more fruits are added, then dropped off, sourced from a different location, etc.). The data here is falsified, but is similar to the data I'm working with.The original data comes through

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be to first convert your `my_info` vector in a matrix using `ncol = 4`. This will split your vector in a matrix/data frame.

Now, you can apply the rule of for `food_type` and `region` and swap any `food_type` or `region` which is present in other columns.

**Note:** I request OP to check data once, it seems every 4 elements are not able to make a complete row with description provided by OP.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(my_info, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))

names(df) <- c("Foodtype", "Region", "Food", "Location")

food_type <- c("Fruits","Vegetables","Meats")
region <- c("North America","Europe")

t(apply(df,1,function(x){
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    #One can think of writing a swap function here. 
    if(x[i] %in% region ){
      temp = x[i]
      x[i] = x[2]
      x[2] = temp
    }
    #Swap any food_type wrongly placed in other column
    if(x[i] %in% food_type ){
      temp = x[i]
      x[i] = x[1]
      x[1] = temp
    }

  }
  x
}))


#       Foodtype       Region          Food         Location  
# [1,] "Fruits"       "North America" "Apples"     "Michigan"
# [2,] "Pomegranates" "Europe"        "Greece"     "Oranges" 
# [3,] "Vegetables"   "North America" "Italy"      "Potatoes"
# [4,] "Idaho"        "Europe"        "California" "Avocados"
# [5,] "Meats"        "North America" "Artichokes" "Italy"   
# [6,] "Fruits"       "North America" "Beef"       "Illinois"
#
```

Comment: That's right, not every 4 elements creates a row. The original data comes to me in something like this https://i.imgur.com/X9feVEW.png. The list changes every day and I don't want to have to manually enter the data every day into a data frame before I can do my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I have a long solution, but should work as long as food and location are always in the same order.

First creating a few data.frames with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

info <- data_frame(my_info = my_info) 
region <- data_frame(region_id = region, region = region)
food_type <- data_frame(food_type_id = food_type, food_type)
```

Next creating a data.frame that joins all of these together and fill missing values with `tidyr` and removing the rows we do not need. Then The most important trick is the last one, creating a cols column **based on the assumption that the order is always the same!**

```
library(tidyr)

df <- info %>% 
  left_join(food_type, by = c("my_info" = "food_type_id")) %>% 
  left_join(region, by = c("my_info" = "region_id")) %>% 
  fill(food_type) %>% 
  group_by(food_type) %>% 
  fill(region) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(region) & !(my_info == region)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(cols = rep(c("food", "location"), group_size(.)/2 ))
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   my_info      food_type  region        cols    
   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>         <chr>   
 1 Apples       Fruits     North America food    
 2 Michigan     Fruits     North America location
 3 Pomegranates Fruits     Europe        food    
 4 Greece       Fruits     Europe        location
 5 Oranges      Fruits     Europe        food    
 6 Italy        Fruits     Europe        location
 7 Beef         Meats      North America food    
 8 Illinois     Meats      North America location
 9 Potatoes     Vegetables North America food    
10 Idaho        Vegetables North America location
11 Avocados     Vegetables North America food    
12 California   Vegetables North America location
13 Artichokes   Vegetables Europe        food    
14 Italy        Vegetables Europe        location
```

Next use `tidyr` to spread the cols into food and location columns.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(food_type, region, cols) %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(cols, my_info) %>% 
  select(-ind)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   food_type, region [5]
  food_type  region        food         location  
  <chr>      <chr>         <chr>        <chr>     
1 Fruits     Europe        Pomegranates Greece    
2 Fruits     Europe        Oranges      Italy     
3 Fruits     North America Apples       Michigan  
4 Meats      North America Beef         Illinois  
5 Vegetables Europe        Artichokes   Italy     
6 Vegetables North America Potatoes     Idaho     
7 Vegetables North America Avocados     California
```

This can all be done in one go, just remove the intermediate step of creating a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three alternatives.  All of them use `na.locf0` from zoo and the `cn` vector only shown in the first.

**1)** Let `cn` be a vector the same length as `my_info` which identifies which column number of the output that element of `my_info` belongs to.  Let `cdef` be an output column definition vector of 1:4 with the output column names as its names.  Then for each output column create a vector the same length as `my_info` whose rows corresponding to that column and NAs for the other elements.  Then use `na.locf0` to fill in the NA values and take the elements corresponding to column 4.

```
library(zoo)

cn <- (my_info %in% food_type) + 2 * (my_info %in% region)
cn[cn == 0] <- 3:4

cdef <- c(food_type = 1, region = 2, food = 3, location = 4)

m <- sapply(cdef, function(i) na.locf0(ifelse(cn == i, my_info, NA))[cn == 4])
```

giving:

```
> m
     food_type    region          food           location    
[1,] "Fruits"     "North America" "Apples"       "Michigan"  
[2,] "Fruits"     "Europe"        "Pomegranates" "Greece"    
[3,] "Fruits"     "Europe"        "Oranges"      "Italy"     
[4,] "Vegetables" "North America" "Potatoes"     "Idaho"     
[5,] "Vegetables" "North America" "Avocados"     "California"
[6,] "Vegetables" "Europe"        "Artichokes"   "Italy"     
[7,] "Meats"      "North America" "Beef"         "Illinois"
```

We have created character matrix output since the output is entirely character but if you want a data frame anyways then use:

```
as.data.frame(mm, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**2)** Alternately, we can create `m` from `cn` by putting `my_info[i]` into position (i, cn[i]) of an n x 4 matrix mm of NAs, using `na.locf` to fill in the NAs and taking those rows corresponding to column 4.

```
n <- length(my_info)
m2 <- na.locf(replace(matrix(NA, n, 4), cbind(1:n, cn), my_info))[cn == 4, ]
colnames(m2) <- c("food_type", "region", "food", "location")

identical(m2, m) # test
## [1] TRUE
```

**3)** A third alternative for creating `m` from `cn` is to construct the matrix column by column like this:

```
m3 <- cbind( food_type = na.locf0(ifelse(cn == 1, my_info, NA))[cn == 3], 
        region = na.locf0(ifelse(cn == 2, my_info, NA))[cn == 3], 
        food = my_info[cn == 3], 
        location = my_info[cn == 4])

identical(m, m3) # test
## [1] TRUE
```